# Ways to change the spritesheet in runtime?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite-sheet

I have a problem changing my sprite sheet during gameTime, in a game that I'm making.

My idea was to create a string, and change the "content" of that string when a sudden "if"(being a certain objective) appears.
For example:
(this is in the update method of my main Class)

```
string Rusher = "Character/FirstRusher";

player = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>(Rusher), new Vector2(650, 600), 82, 42);
```

(other part of the update method, a little more down)

```
if(scorepoints == 20)
    speed = 10;

Rusher = "Character/SecondRusher";
```

Well, the texture FirstRusher is still the one being used after 20.
What should I do? And thank you in advance for those who help me with this issue.

Comment: You have to re-create the player object with the new texture...

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to save the position where he is at the precise moment, or am I?
I mean, how do I save that Vector 2D? In a variable? Does it change during the gameTime?

Comment: maybe a little more smoke and mirrors.  create 2 Players and switch them out when the conditions arises

Comment: That seems like an idea.
I already tried creating more than 1 player from my Class Animation, and load all the textures on each player, so I basicly control them all at the same time.
Now, the trick is in the draw method, right?
I used an "if" there, didn't work
Sorry for being such a beginner at this...